# Allow connection only from 2 ips

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I need to block all connection on port 30000. I alredy did that , with command like that

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s IP_HERE -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DROP
```

but now i need 2 ips , how i could do that?

That ips , that i need to allow: localhost, and other ip. Lest say one of google.com ips

Comment: Use two iptables rules?

Comment: @CraigWatson that is the same as "go and google that question"

Comment: Not really, your question was "allow connection from two IP addresses" and I proposed using two separate rules rather than just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the logic (accept if.. instead of drop if not..) in your iptables rules and use two rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s FIRST_IP_HERE -p tcp --dport 30001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s SECOND_IP_HERE -p tcp --dport 30001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DROP
```

Comment: That did work , ty!

Comment: Oh and plz , dislike other person... using links on stack / server sites are very bad... what if someone will delete that site?

Answer (score 2):

To drop all traffic but allow two specific IP addresses, you will need to use three rules in this order (iptables rules are processed in order, so the order matters):

- Allow IP 1
- Allow IP 2
- Drop all

If multiple IPs are on the same subnet, you can use either CIDR or IP/mask notation.

You can also do something more fancy like create a chain, see [this link](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/210571).

Comment: Its localhost ip , and ip that not localhost :P  btw , i asked HOW I DO THAT. Idk how to do multiple iptables rules.

Comment: I don't understand the point - can you edit your question with more detail?

Comment: I need to allow only 2 ips , but idk how

Comment: See my answer. You use two rules, one for each IP you want to block. You'll need to remove the ! in your first rule, as it currently reads "drop all traffic on port 3000 *apart from* this IP" and you want the inverse for two specific IP addresses.

Comment: Just edited my answer now that you've clarified the question.

Comment: Using links... why i cant de vote you ? (